# Is there a formalization of automatic-splicing data structures?

Tags: data-structures, type-theory

I'm wondering if there is some formalization, type theoretical analysis, or similar for data structures that automatically "splice" in an associative way. Barring a perfect citation, I'd be interested to know if there are other keywords I should be looking for in this space.

Examples are particularly common in term-rewriting languages, such as [Tuples and Matricies in Purelang](http://puredocs.bitbucket.org/pure.html#splicing-tuples-and-matrices) or [Sequence in Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html).

I'm also interested in one particularly challenging question with these constructs: How should "quoting" (to prevent splicing) be represented and handled?